# How to expand trimmed body text to full body text in the same Views page?

Tags: views, 7

I have a view in Drupal 7 where I am showing the node title and its body as trimmed text, as shown in this screenprint:

[image]

I need to show full body text after click on the ***Read more*** link, but in the same page. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... provides a display style plugin for the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.
>   It will take the results and display them as a JQuery [accordion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI)), using the first field as the header for the accordion rows.
>
> For Drupal 7 the module integrates the [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) plugin as a views style plugin. You can configure the options provided by the jQuery UI plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module `Read More` https://www.drupal.org/project/readmore
The field formatter expands the body text using JS when the `Read More` link is clicked.

Comment: I have download this .. But I am not getting how to use this.Please help me

Comment: In the views settings edit the body field. Under the `Formatter` you will get a new option `Read More`. Select the option and configure the settings below it. That is all you need. Hope this helps.
You can refer to this screenshot http://picpaste.com/Capture-l42LNyY9.PNG

Comment: Thanks a lot..I also need to show extra info after click on read more link

Comment: Like I need to show related term link .. only on after click on read more link.

Comment: If you want to show any extra field then `Read More` will not help you. It will be a better option to choose `ctools` modal popup or `Colorbox` to show the details in a popup.